# Antiderivative Supremum inequality $F(b)-F(a) \le (b-a)\sup\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Hello everyone I am suppose to show the following:

> Let F be the antiderivative of f, show that
>   $$ F(b)-F(a) \le \sup\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\} $$

I figured I could use the Mean-Value-Theorem since $F'(x)=f(x)$ so
$\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=f(x)$ for some $x \in [a,b]$ but then the $(b-a)$ part gets in the way. Maybe some trick with the more general form $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f(x)}{g'(x)}$?

I think one could solve it using some facts about the Riemann Integral and upper Darboux sums like:

$$F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(x) dx \le \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \sup_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(t)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$

since it has all the parts but we are not allowed to use this yet.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

There was an error in the assignment. It was to show that:

$$ F(b)-F(a) \le (b-a)\sup\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\} $$

Which is just the Mean-Value-Theorem:

$$\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=f(x)\le\sup\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$$

and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not true, a couterexample is $f(x)=1$.
So that $F(x)=x+c$, then if $b>a+1$ $F(b)-F(a)=b-a>1=\sup_{[a,b]}f(x)$.

Comment: Yes indeed, the Professor just posted an update to the assignment. Thank you